# How to check dict.has_key(k,x) with 2 variables

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, key

I have formed a dictionary with 2 keys assigning to a single dictionary value, for example:

```
my_dict[x, y] = ...
my_dict[a, u] = ...
```

Now how would i be able to use the `has_key()` method for 2 key variables, x and y like such:

```
if my_dict.has_key(x,y) == True:
    Do Something
else:
    Do something else
```

d is a matrix, that uses pdict values that i call from a variable f and g, but all you need to know is that they are variable names x,y being used as key values in pdict.

Comment: Could you please provide an example dictionary in valid Python syntax?  As it is, we will have to guess how your dictionary is *really* looking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated for a long time now, you should use the `in` operator instead:

```
if (x, y) in my_dict:
    # whatever
```

Note that your dictionary does not have "two keys".  It probably uses a `tuple` of two elements as a key, but that tuple is a single object.

Comment: Thank you, i was unaware that it was using my 2 variables in a tuple, and my program works fine now, thank you!

Comment: @Sean: The comma is actually what signals a tuple in Python, not the parens.  This is a bit confusing due to a few exceptions to this rule.

Answer (score 6):

If you used a sequence as a key like this:

```
d[1,2] = 3
```

the key is implicitly converted to a tuple. In a function call that expects
a single argument, you need to specify the tuple explicitly:

```
d.has_key((1,2))
```

Comment: beat me to the answer, what i was going to say, but let me add, that the reason that assigning 2 variables (or more) to a dictionary key will work in python is because it combines them into a tuple, (into 1 value) so when you search through the dict, you must always provide a single value to the key, so you must combine your variables into 1 value (hence the tuple)

Comment: Your comment is spot on; my original answer was poorly worded.